# Access to an ASP.NET MVC 5 controller throw a Java application using http Post and Get

Tags: java, asp.net-mvc, http, http-post, http-get

I' building a web app using MVC 5, and i want to get data from a controller with a java application.

How can i make the connection and save the data in some variable?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very generic so I can't provide a concrete code for a solution.

But you can get data by making a [HTTP request](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/) to an endpoint of your MVC app. Now comes the question what is your MVC action (in the controller) is returning? - HTML, JSON. Depending on that you will have to set some [headers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) for the request you will make and finally deserialize the returned data to java objects.